# Android show EditText.setError() above the EditText and not below it

Tags: android, android-edittext

When i call EditText.setError(); the error appears below the edittext, and makes it impossible to interact with the View below the EditText. Is it possible to show the error above the EditText? Google doesn't seem to have the answer(Or i'm using wrong search terms).

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1Uth.png]

Comment: I do not think so. But when the EditText is not focused the error popup is not shown so it is not blocking the below EditText. Lots of apps are using it that way.

Comment: The only way to make the EditText lose focus is to touch another View. But if there are only two Views on the screen and the error of one is completely blocking the other, then it's not even possible to touch another view.

Comment: The error popup never fills the whole width. I can see "Kullan" word is already visible. In my app, the edittexts have little more margin and the second edittext is clickable even if the error is shown. Furthermore user should write a valid email address right? When he does that the error will be gone and he can click the second edittext.

Comment: Yes in the example screenshot you are right, but there are cases where the user input doesn't have to be valid(It's just a warning), and the errors warning covers the whole View.

Comment: I don't think it is the right way to use setError() function for just warnings. You may want to use Croutons or Toasts for that.

Answer (score 1):

The Crouton Library seems to be a better way to display errors when validating forms. See some reasons [here](http://blog.zasadnyy.org.ua/2013/08/android-form-validation-right-way.html)

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to take one textview with custom background above the 1st edittext and align_parent_right=true.
  Rather than setting setError() to edittext set the visibility(visible/invisible) to the textview.
  For that red drawable placed at right side in edittext, u can set drawableRight to edittext with setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds() method.